# False positive respondsToSelector with UIApplicationDelegate leading to NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate

In short, the following code calls an existing selector in the super class, and then gives an NSInvalidException:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:)])
{
    [super applicationWillResignActive:application];
}
```

This gives the following log exception:

- *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[aAppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b5d360'

---

To elaborate... I have a base application delegate (from our new company library) declared as:

I have a base application delegate class, BaseAppDelegate. It is declared as:

```
@interface CoAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

It implements:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    DebugLog(@"*** ACTIVE ****");
}
```

It does not implement @selector(applicationWillResignActive:) - or at least what I mean is that I have not specifically written out code for that method. It can't be found in the .h or .m file.

My app has an app delegate that inherits from CoAppDelegate as:

```
@interface aAppDelegate : CoAppDelegate <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

I implement both of the above methods as:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:)])
    {
        [super applicationWillResignActive:application];
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:)])
    {   
        [super applicationDidBecomeActive:application];
    }
}
```

When the app launches, I get the debug output "*** ACTIVE ****" - as it should.

When I send my app to the background I get that NSInvalidArgumentException stating that the responder does not exist - and it does not exist, so this is the correct exception to throw.

What I need to know is WHY does respondsToSelector give a YES when I am expecting to see a NO? What is the little subtle thing that I am missing?

Comment: I have to ask why you are doing this?  You know the API of the base class of your class, so you know which methods it does and doesn't implement.  There's no need for the tests.  In fact there's no need for your implementations of these methods.

Comment: the reason is a bit convoluted, and really boils down to being so new (to iPhone, from java...) that when I can't get something to work one way, I try something else... a few reps down that cycle and I get to the above (unnecessary) code. Despite being unneeded, it still posed a question that I really wanted to understand (even thought the "real" code was fixed without using this method). In Java I could use reflection to do something similar, but the difference would be that the reflection on the super class would not include methods on the child class. So I really just wanted to understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `[super class]` you should use `[self superclass]`:

```
[[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(method)]
```

Comment: This may not always be true - see my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 9):

You should use [`instancesRespondToSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/instancesRespondToSelector:) for the following reason stated in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCEHCCE):

> You cannot test whether an object inherits a method from its superclass by sending `respondsToSelector:` to the object using the `super` keyword.
>
> This method will still be testing the object as a whole, not just the superclass’s implementation. Therefore, sending `respondsToSelector:` to `super` is equivalent to sending it to `self`. Instead, you must invoke the `NSObject` class method `instancesRespondToSelector:` directly on the object’s superclass.

Your subclass' code should look like this:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    if ([[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:_cmd])
    {
        [super applicationWillResignActive:application];
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    if ([[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:_cmd])
    {   
        [super applicationDidBecomeActive:application];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jacob. And a vote up for introducing me to _cmd. (and since this question is a new-guy type, heres a link to some info on _cmd to save the next guy from a google search: [Secret Life of _cmd](http://6tringle.com/blog/2009/SecretLifeOf_cmd.html))

Comment: @Richard You're very welcome! I figured it was being put to good use for DRY purposes, no need to wrap yourself in your own selector, just use `_cmd`! :)

Comment: The code as written actually doesn't work. Unfortunately, calling [super class] still gives the class name of the self object. Which means that this code still checks basically if "self" itself responds to the selector it is already responding to. As the same documentation lower down suggests, I changed to code to directly refrence CoAppDelegate (name of super class), and finally it is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:<selector>];
```

may produces undesired results in some special cases. It is better to explicitly state class name instead of self:

```
[[<ClassName> superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:<selector>];
```

**Explanation:**

Consider example:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)foo;
- (void)bar;
@end

@interface A : NSObject <MyProtocol>
@end

@implementation A 
- (void)foo {
     //Do sth
}
@end

@interface B : A
@end

@implementation B
- (void)bar {
    //B may not know which methods of MyProtocol A implements, so it checks
    if ([[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(bar)]) {
        [super bar];
    }
    //Do sth
}
@end

@interface C : B
@end

@implementation C
@end
```

Imagine then following code:

```
C *c = [C new];
[c bar];
```

This code ... crashes! Why? Let's dig through what's going on when calling bar method on C instance 'c'. [self superclass] returns... B, since self is instance of C. Of course, B instances reponds to bar, so the body of if is entered. However, [super bar] tries to call super implementation from B's perspective, so tries to call bar on A, which results in crash!

That's why I suggest to replace [self superclass] with precise [B superclass] - which solves the problem.